# What aspects of written dialogue are important when giving characters a unique voice?

Tags: style, dialogue

I have a project that I am working on in which I need to write quite a few fictional informal email correspondences between pairs of characters. I am not using these characters in any other context.

I am working with a relatively large number of characters (12 ish) and have neither the time nor the need to fully flesh out each in great detail.

I think I am doing a good job keeping the characters interesting and unique in terms of the actual content of their conversations, but I am aware that their writing styles are all a very similar.

I have tried to identify some basic variables I can use to determine the character's writing style. So far I mainly have the following:

- Tendency to over/under comma
- Typical sentence length
- Commonly used phrases/sayings (oh god, yeah-but-no, take the world by its nipples and twist)
- Expressions of humour (haha, lol, :D)

What are some other ways I can differentiate my characters' writing styles? Or put another way, what are some things that give away a common writer that I should try and avoid?